# How could I play different audio files as they were only one file? With silent fragments

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I want to play different audio files as they were only one file. For example, I've got five mp3 files:

- audio1.mp3 of 10 seconds
- audio2.mp3 of 30 seconds
- audio3.mp3 of 10 seconds
- audio4.mp3 of 20 seconds
- audio5.mp3 of 30 seconds

Then I want to play the 5 files in sequence but with silence in the middle of that files:

[audio1, silence 100 seconds, audio2, silence 20 seconds, audio3, audio4, silence 5 sec, audio5]

The major problem that I think it could happen is in the "pause" state of that silence (because I don't want to record the silence).

Thank you.

Comment: Uh... Can't you just pause between files?

Comment: Counting the time that has been passed during the pause?